# How to send data to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using express and I need to send dynamically data to the app.get() method.
On my index page I have a list of topics and on click I need to send the name of the element which is the needed data

```
 <% data.forEach((row)=> {%>
       <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
         <li class="list-group-item">
   <a href="/question" class="stretched-link" name="<%= row.TopicID %>" id="sendObject">
     <%= row.Headline %>
   </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<%}) %>
```

I tried it with ajax but I didnt know how because I am new to javascript.
Any ideas on how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `a` element shouldn't have a `name` attribute unless you are linking *to* the point on the page where the `a` element is (and even then, `name` on `a` was superseded by `id` on *anything* **two decades ago**).

If you want to include data when a link is clicked: **encode it in the URL** in the `href` attribute.

Either as a [query string](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) or as a [path parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)